# How do I use HTTPS replication with iOS Couchbase Mobile?

Tags: ios, https, erlang, couchdb, couchbase

I'm using iOS Couchbase Mobile to have a couchdb server on an iPad that uses replication to sync with a server on https://cloudant.com. cloudant uses HTTPS, and when I try replicating on the iPad, i just get spammed by errors.

This is a known issue, as seen on [this FAQ article](http://support.cloudant.com/customer/portal/articles/359322-i%E2%80%99m-having-trouble-replicating-in-out-of-cloudant). It recommends using 1.0.2 to fix the issue, but how do i know if I'm running it on Erlang R14?

#### Version Info

- On myserver.cloudant.com: `{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2","cloudant_build":"1.3.49"}`
- On iOS Couchbase Mobile: `{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.0.0-beta"}`

(For some reason it says I'm using 2.0.0-beta on iOS, even though I downloaded [this version (2.0.1)](http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/iOS).)

Here's the kind of error that I get:

```
[info] [<0.327.0>] Retrying HEAD request to https://user:password@mycompany.cloudant.com/mydb/ in 16.0 seconds due to error {'EXIT',
{no_ssl_server,
    {gen_server,call,
        [<0.347.0>,
         {send_req,
             {{url,
                  "https://user:password@mycompany.cloudant.com/mydb/",
                  "mycompany.cloudant.com",443,"mycompany","password",
                  "/mydb/",https,hostname},
              [{"Accept","application/json"},
               {"User-Agent","CouchDB/2.0.0-beta"}],
              head,<<>>,
              [{response_format,binary},
               {inactivity_timeout,30000},
               {is_ssl,true},
               {socket_options,[{keepalive,true},{nodelay,false}]},
               {ssl_options,[{depth,3},{verify,verify_none}]}],
              infinity}},
         infinity]}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a "[nightly build](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mobile-couchbase/wXS5cgMWraQ)" that enables SSL support in CouchBase Mobile for iOS, but it was never QA'd and it never got released in a "stable build". I have contacted someone who was working on Couchbase Mobile for iOS, and he told me that I should use [TouchDB](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The issue of enabling https connection between CouchBase Mobile for iOS and another CouchDB/CouchBase instance is also discussed here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mobile-couchbase/DDHSisVWEyo/hxtlVRhQtwkJ

Apparently it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB provides information on current Erlang version in it's **Server** response header, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.0.1 (Erlang OTP/R13B)  <----------------------
Date: Fri, 05 Nov 2010 14:57:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

Since error message says it can't find HTTPS server, you probably want to check it via plain HTTP.

**BTW** [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/) are completely different database products (both use Erlang platform) and it seems like you are using them interchangeably. Maybe the problem is that you are trying to connect to CouchDB with CouchBase client or something like that?

Comment: "CouchDB and CouchBase are completely different database products (both use Erlang platform)". Really? I thought CouchBase was a product based on CouchDB?